# C++: Clean way to create a std::map of function pointers

Tags: c++, cmake, stdmap

I want to create a shared library, which just contains a std::map to look up function pointers. The purpose is to merge several static libraries (plugins), which all offer the same type function. 
Each plugin has an unique integer id.
However, only libraries which are available at compile time should be collected. Currently i am using a mix of cmake and the c++ preprocessor:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(EXISTS ${plugin1})
    message("found plugin1")
    include_directories(${plugin1}/include)
    add_definitions(-DPLUGIN1)
    find_library(plugin1Lib plugin1 ${plugin1}/lib)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${plugin1Lib})
endif()
```

shared library:

```
#ifdef PLUGIN1 
    #include "plugin1.h"
#endif


static std::map<int, pluginFunctionPtr> userPlugins= { 
    #ifdef PLUGIN1
    {20, funcPlugin1} ,
    #endif
};
```

It works well, but i think it's really complicated. Is there a better way to achieve what i want? 
Thank you!

Comment: Considered self registration at static initialization time?

Comment: @Yakk would this require the plugins to know about this collection in which they are registering themselves?  previously this concept was only present in the shared library and may not belong in the plugins

Comment: Is the desire that we want to be able to add new plugins without having to modify the shared library's code?

Comment: @brian sure, or have make make a cpp file with a static initializer with a per library unique define.  Which is much like your system, but maybe simpler.

Comment: The present system works very well, but i was just interested if there is a more elegant solution. What is the static initializer approach?